# pass parameter value from one method to another two methods aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm little bit confused here, I'ts messed up,help. In this line of code:

dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + Counter1;

in next 2 methods Button6_Click and Button7_Click this Label37.Text value should be incremented for one each time when user press the button.So I want this label value in next methods to start to count from current value for one each time on button click.I do this with viewState, it work perfect just for one of the buttons, on the secound button doesnt work.It seems to me that it keeping previous value of Label37, but each click on btnTest_Click it shoud have new value in variable decimal newValue.How to fix this?

```
      protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        if (Session["Markici"] != null)
        {

            var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;

            decimal old = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("Kolicina");

            decimal oldIznos = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkIznos");
            decimal VkDanok = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<decimal>("VkDanok");
            string Cena1 = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<string>("Cena1");
            int TarifaID = dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Field<Int16>("TarifaID");


            decimal newValue = old - 1; //
           Label37.Text = newValue.ToString();



            decimal newIznos = oldIznos - Convert.ToDecimal(Cena1);

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("Kolicina", newValue.ToString());      
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].SetField("VkIznos", newIznos.ToString());


            if (old == 0)
            {
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex].Delete();
                dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

            }
            GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }

         public int Counter
        {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Counter"] != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]);
            }

            else
                return 0;
        }
        set { ViewState["Counter"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new      SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["string2"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;


        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT pkid,Artikal,Vid,EdMera,TarifaID,Cena1 FROM Artikli WHERE Artikal= 'N KREM SUPA OD SPANA]++' AND Cena1 = 130.00", conn);
        //brojac za kolicina 
        count++;
        decimal noofcount = count;
        Session["kolicina"] = noofcount;
        Label5.Text = Session["kolicina"].ToString();//ViewState["count"].ToString();//

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Label9.Text = (string)reader["pkid"].ToString();
            Label3.Text = (string)reader["Artikal"].ToString();
            Label23.Text = (string)reader["Vid"].ToString();           
            Label10.Text = (string)reader["EdMera"].ToString();
            Label7.Text = (string)reader["TarifaID"].ToString();               
            Label4.Text = (string)reader["Cena1"].ToString();



            decimal cena = Convert.ToDecimal(Label5.Text);//kolicina
            decimal kolicina = Convert.ToDecimal(Label4.Text);//cena

            //vkIznos

            decimal mnoz = cena * kolicina;
            Label6.Text = mnoz.ToString();
            Convert.ToDecimal(Label6.Text);


        }

        conn.Close();

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];

        if (Label37.Text == "0")
        {
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Label5.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Counter = Counter + 1;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + Counter;
        }

        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Artikal"] = Label3.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Cena1"] = Label4.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkIznos"] = Label6.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkDanok"] = Label8.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["EdMera"] = Label10.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["ArtikalID"] = Label9.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Vid"] = Label23.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["TarifaID"] = Label7.Text;

        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
        GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        RemoveDuplicates(dt);

    }

       public int Counter1
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Counter1"] != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter1"]);
            }

            else
                return 0;
        }
        set { ViewState["Counter1"] = value; }
    }
    protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["string2"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT pkid,Artikal,Vid,EdMera,TarifaID,Cena1 FROM Artikli WHERE Artikal= 'N KREM SUPA OD SVE@I PE^URKI++' AND Cena1 = 160.00", conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        count1++;
        float noofcount = count1;
        Session["kolicina2"] = noofcount;
        Label11.Text = Session["kolicina2"].ToString(); //ViewState["count"].ToString(); //

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Label35.Text = (string)reader["pkid"].ToString();
            Label12.Text = (string)reader["Artikal"].ToString();
            Label33.Text = (string)reader["Vid"].ToString();
            Label34.Text = (string)reader["EdMera"].ToString();
            Label14.Text = (string)reader["TarifaID"].ToString();
            Label13.Text = (string)reader["Cena1"].ToString();




            //iznos
            decimal mnoz = Convert.ToDecimal(Label11.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(Label13.Text);
            Label17.Text = mnoz.ToString();
            decimal.Parse(Label17.Text);

            decimal cena;
            cena = Convert.ToDecimal(Label13.Text);
            decimal kolicina;
            kolicina = Convert.ToDecimal(Label11.Text);
            decimal iznos;
            iznos = Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text);

            Session["cena1"] = Label13.Text;
            Session["iznos1"] = Label17.Text;






            conn.Close();
        }

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];

        if (Label37.Text == "0")
        {
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Label11.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + Counter1;// Label37.Text;//Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + 3;
        }

        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Artikal"] = Label12.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Cena1"] = Label13.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkIznos"] = Label17.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkDanok"] = Label18.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["EdMera"] = Label34.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["ArtikalID"] = Label35.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Vid"] = Label33.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["TarifaID"] = Label14.Text;

        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
        GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        RemoveDuplicates(dt);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to track individual button clicks? as Button1 - 5 times, Button2- 3 times.... or you want incremental count whatever button is clicked?

Comment: to track individual button clicks depend on this-> decimal newValue = old - 1; //
           Label37.Text = newValue.ToString();

Comment: Code is completly messed with ViewState["Counter1"] ,ViewState["count"]  and Counter properties. Either use properties or viewstate. Also, name variables as per button like button6_count,button7_count. It will make code more readable and easy to find bug if any.

Comment: In this situation what could I do?

Comment: Do, one by one button. Also, this line is suspicious decimal newValue = old - 1;           Label37.Text = newValue.ToString();

Comment: btnTest is one button which is in dataTable and is created dynamically when is added new row